# A formula for the sum of the triangular numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Let $t(n)$ denote the n$^{th}$ triangular number.

Let $T(n)$ denote the sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers.

Is there a formula for $T(n)$?

Comment: I don't see an obvious reason to create such a tag. Could you elaborate why you think triangular numbers need a separate tag?

Comment: For reference: you want the [tetrahedral numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$nth$ triangular number is the sum of $n$ consecutive natural numbers from starting which is simply $n(n+1)/2$. You want sum of first $n$  triangular numbers. Just take the sum $\Sigma_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$.

Comment: I think mine will be easier to evaluate

Comment: Actually you claimed something and then proved it. It is not always an easy task to make claims.

Comment: @abc... it is poor manners to troll for upvotes

Answer (score 20):

Formula for T(n): $$T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$
Proof: we can prove it in an inductive way.

Base case:$$T(1)=\frac{1*2*3}{6}=1$$
Let n=k. We have $T(n+1)=T(n)+t(n+1).$

Therefore $$T(k+1)=T(k)+t(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6}+\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)+3(k+1)(k+2)}{6}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{6}$$

Q.E.D

Comment: Be happy +1.....

Comment: Strictly speaking, this proof isn't valid because it uses the formula it's trying to prove to establish the base case. Better to simply compute the "sum" of the first triangular number explicitly.

Comment: @DavidZ: I take your point, but I read that line as stating that $T(1)$ (ie the first triangular number) is equal to ${1\cdot 2 \cdot 3}\over 6$ (ie formula we're trying to prove) - so no assumption is necessarily being made.

Comment: @psmears Oh, OK, I see what you mean. Well, in that case I would scale back my criticism to merely say that it's not explained well.

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align}
t(r)&=\binom {r+1}2&&=\frac {r(r+1)}2\\
T(n)&=\sum_{r=1}^n t(r)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n \binom {r+1}2\\
&=\binom {n+2}3&&=\frac {n(n+1)(n+2)}6\end{align}$$

Comment: $(+1)$ No words; pure math(s)

Comment: @user477343 - Yes, indeed :) Thanks!

Comment: `pure' math(s) includes words, sometimes, and what's more this answer contradicts several others given here.

Comment: @dbx - No contradiction - the end result is the same i.e. $\binom {n+2}3$. The $3$ is the expanded form is a typo which has been corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Since the $k$-th triangular number is $T(k)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, so your sum is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\biggl(
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n k\biggr)
$$
The second summation is $T(n)$, the first summation is
$$
\frac{1}{3}n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(n+1)
$$
(a nice way to memorize it), you find it in several places (the book “Concrete Mathematics” by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik features several derivations of the formula).

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)}{12}\cdot(2n+1+3)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}.$$

I used that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the $n$-th  triangle number.

Comment: @abc... I added something. See now.

Comment: Yes... it makes sense now.

Comment: @abc... I think it was already.